# Prepending to mutable.LinkedList without copying in Scala

Tags: performance, list, scala

I need to build up a list very quickly.
My idea was to use a mutable.LinkedList and grow by prepending.
However I found only the operator +: for prepending and it produces
a copy of the list, which is surprising, given that the list is mutable.

Is there a way to prepend and modify the list in place?

Comment: One approach which may give you the performance you need, is to build up the list by appending, and then simply call `reverse()` on the result once it's fully populated.

Comment: @Andrzej Appending is slow. As best I understand the scala doc there is no method for prepending in place, but maybe I am missing something. Unneeded copying is not good for perfomance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is how you are supposed to use it, from a quick glance:

```
val newList = new LinkedList(newElem, existingList)
```

Note though that it is deprecated in Scala 2.11 and might get removed in the future.

Comment: This implies copying too. It seems that LinkedList is not the right container, but ListBuffer might be the one to use.

Comment: The mutable linked list contains one element and the rest, so prepend is very cheap and does not involve copying, you can see the source of it here for yourself: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedList.scala#L102

Comment: OK. I mistakenly thought that new automatically implies copying. Thanks.